# Java OutofMemory Strange Error

Tags: java, performance, memory-management

I have started my `jar` from command line using following command

```
java -Xms1200m -Xmx1500m -jar xxx.jar
```

and I am creating `BufferedImage` which is in size 12600 * 12600 means it requires

*606 MB* of memory in following code

```
TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(sr);

            String pngFile = "Style-" + shoeViewer.getCurrentStyle() + "_"
                    + shoeViewer.getSelectedMetadata().getSizeLabel()
                    + "_400DPI" + ".png";

            File outputFile = new File(pngFile);

            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(fo);

            long now = System.currentTimeMillis();

            t.transcode(input, null);
```

when I am debugging memory usage before executing above lines , my Runtime shows

I need 606 MB of memory and *1100* MB is still free .

So when I run above codes after 34 mins it throws `OutOfMemory` Exception .

**what is the problem  ? is it process problem or heap problem ? why it takes 34 minutes ??**

My PC configuration is following

```
Windows 32bit XP Service Pack2 Home Edition
Amd Athlon (tm) 7750 Dual Core 2.71 GHz
2GB of DDR2 RAM
java version "1.7.0_17"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_17-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

please, help me solve out this problem.

below is the exception stack tarce with debugging messages.

before running above code i changed VM argument to following

```
java -Xms900m -Xmx1024m -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio=40 -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70 -jar myjar.jar
```

**Building XML Document from SVG Reader....
 Build completed of XML Document from SVG Reader....
 Converting modified XML Document to String Writer....
 Conversion complete of modified XML Document to String Writer....
 claimedBytes 766 Avaialbel Bytes 900189232
 Memory Statastics------------------------
Total memory is bytes: 912326656         Total memory is megabytes: 870
Used memory is bytes: 9308384    Used memory is megabytes: 8
Freememory is bytes: 900189096   Free memory is megabytes: 858**

---

transcoding started at :Sun Mar 24 11:09:59 IST 2013

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap spa
ce
        at java.awt.image.DataBufferInt.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.image.SinglePixelPackedSampleModel.createDataBuffer(Unknown
Source)
        at java.awt.image.Raster.createWritableRaster(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.updateWorkingBuffers(Sta
ticRenderer.java:536)
        at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.repaint(StaticRenderer.j
ava:375)
        at org.apache.batik.gvt.renderer.StaticRenderer.repaint(StaticRenderer.j
ava:344)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTran
scoder.java:111)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstra
ctTranscoder.java:142)
        at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstra
ctTranscoder.java:156)
        at com.mmg.app.eventlistener.PlaceOrderActionListener.save(PlaceOrderAct
ionListener.java:302)
        at com.mmg.app.eventlistener.PlaceOrderActionListener.saveCanvas(PlaceOr
derActionListener.java:270)
        at com.mmg.app.eventlistener.PlaceOrderActionListener.actionPerformed(Pl
aceOrderActionListener.java:143)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Sour
ce)
        at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: @TReddy if you know the answer then why you fon't give it ?

Comment: @Maroun do you know the answer ?

Comment: What type of object is `t`?

Comment: @ecbrodie ohh sorry i forgot to mention T is PngTransCoder from Apache Batik library.

Comment: You should use the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError flag, and analyze the heap dump. YourKit is an excellent tool for that purpose, but JVisualVM is also easy to use, and free (you can find it in your JDK folder).

Comment: Overall, you should be wrapping your input and output streams into try-catch-finally blocks (or try-with-resources from Java 7). Declare the variable outside of the try and initialize it to null. Initialize it with a constructor and process information as needed in the try. Close the stream (if it is not-null) in finally. I must say that I've never used Apache Batik before so perhaps all my tips are invalid.

Comment: @ecbrodie actually i am encoding a BufferedImage to png file using 400 DPI by batik PNG Encoder.if i use image to encode less than 5000 * 5000 than there is not a problem but when size exceeds this amount the problem starts.

Comment: can you please provide the stack trace of the OOM error?

Comment: @iGili i have updated the question as you requested. i can also provide you heap dump also.

Comment: enable verbose GC (-Xloggc:file) too .That should give an idea of memory usage pattern too.

Comment: @Mihir this could be a UI problem. try to trigger your code from a main method instead of using the action listener. let me know how it went.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even through the raw unencoded image would only fill around 600 MB, the internal representation in the encoder might need more memory depending on how it's implemented. The following example shows how much memory is used when scaling a simple svg file to 12600 x 12600 (32 bit).

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderInput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.TranscoderOutput;
import org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.PNGTranscoder;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        PNGTranscoder t = new PNGTranscoder();
        t.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_WIDTH, new Float(12600));
        t.addTranscodingHint(PNGTranscoder.KEY_HEIGHT, new Float(12600));
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("C:\\StackOverflow\\SVG-logo.svg");
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(fis);
        OutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream("C:\\StackOverflow\\res.png");
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        System.out.println("AllocatedMemory: \t" + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) + " Kb");
        t.transcode(input, output);
        System.out.println("AllocatedMemory: \t" + (Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() / 1024) + " Kb");

        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();

    }
}
```

On my machine the output is:

```
AllocatedMemory:    4096 Kb 
AllocatedMemory:    1677721 Kb
```

So here the program uses 1677 MB to transcode a simple SVG file to a 12600 * 12600 PNG file.

Comment: how much ram do you have in your PC in GB ? how much time it takes to run above code on your PC ?

Comment: OK i tried it on other pc with higher ram and it works , now can you give me PC configuration on which this code runs without any problem ? your JDK configuration and the file size on disk of generated (transcoded) PNG in MB ?

Comment: I have 8 GB in my PC. The file I encode in the program is from wikipedia: [link]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:SVG-logo.svg and it takes about 20 sec. to process on my PC, giving an output file with a size of 1.1 MB. I ran the program from within Eclipse, with no special options.

Comment: another thing test your program with multi colored image and please give me the size of the generated png file and times it takes to generate the file.you can find plenty of multi coloured svgs here http://raphaeljs.com/

Comment: Why not do that yourself ?

Comment: i have only 2GB of RAM currently so i am running Out of memory error.